# Elasticsearch error: failed to parse, document is empty

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am getting this error in Elasticsearch (0.90) API, when i try to index a simple JSON document.

Here's the code:

```
TransportClient client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
String indexName = "searchwriter-" + FORMAT.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
client.prepareIndex(indexName, "trace", String.valueOf(id++)).setOpType(IndexRequest.OpType.INDEX).setSource(inputLine).execute().actionGet();
```

**inputLine** in the above code **is not empty**. Its value is

> {"type":"MasterCard1","name":"Zaheen1"}

Exception below:

```
[2013-12-10 11:26:24,475][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Foxfire] [searchwriter-2013-12-10][0], node[Hamh7CPnQIqqp4pYA-DD9w], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [index {[searchwriter-2013-
12-10][trace][2], source[_na_]}]                                                                                                                                                                
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse, document is empty                                                                                                       
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:530)                                                                                                         
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:452)                                                                                                         
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:341)                                                                                   
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:203)                                                                           
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:533)  
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:418)             
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                                                                                                      
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)                                                                                                      
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I googled, but i couldnt find the reason. Any ideas?

Comment: should type be in the json doc you are sending? Have you tried setting  the source using a XContentBuilder like in the ES examples? ```setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                        .field("message", "trying out Elastic Search")
                    .endObject()``` Is inputline a String of json and if so does it need to be escaped at all?

Answer (score 0):

That should work. So, I would guess that `inputLine` doesn't contain what you think it contains. Try replacing your `inputLine` with a hardcoded version:

```
client.prepareIndex(indexName, "trace", String.valueOf(id++)).setOpType(IndexRequest.OpType.INDEX).setSource("{\"type\":\"MasterCard1\",\"name\":\"Zaheen1\"}").execute().actionGet();
```

to see if it fixes that problem.

And just in case, are you using the same version of elasticsearch on both client and server?